# Unable to fetch file from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am unable to fetch the uploaded image file from the firebase storage because the database stores the url in a public unguessable url form and I cannot seem to figure it out, what is wrong with my code?

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(this);

        //Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, imageUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){

        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SettingsActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait While The Image Is Being Uploaded");
            mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            String current_user_id = mCurrentUser.getUid();
            StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");
            filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        final String download_url = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        mUserDatabase.child("image").setValue(download_url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }

                            }
                        });

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }
            });

        } else if(resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){

            Exception error = result.getError();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can convert your image in bitmap stream and then you can upload it on firebase storage and get downloadable link also easily. You can do something like this below:

```
StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");

Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),imageUri);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,40,baos);
byte[] byt = baos.toByteArray();

UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putBytes(byt);

 uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:"+e.getMessage(),TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,
                                     TastyToast.ERROR).show();

                        }
                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            if(taskSnapshot.getMetadata() != null){

                                Task<Uri> result = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();

                                result.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                         downloadUrl = Uri.parse(uri.toString());

                                       // In downloadUri variable you will get your 
                                           image downloadable link
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Would you mind checking the entire code on my github ? I still have problems figuring this out sorry.

Comment: https://github.com/bakedknight/linkmsn there ya go. The java file in the above code is SettingsActivity.java

Comment: What error are you getting, have you tried my code.

Comment: well the main error is how the url is being stored in the database due to which when I try to fetch it, it is unable to do so. The image url is storing in the database in the form of com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@e4bfb58. As long as that is the form in which url is stored, I cannot possibly fetch it. I need it stored in the from of actual download url of the image uploaded in the firebase storage

Comment: First check whether image is stored in your firebase storage or not.If image is there then get its download link using `task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString()`.After getting download url you can store it in firebase database.I have posted answer above on how to get download url after uploading image to firebase storage.

Comment: The image is stored in the storage but I still can't seem to store the direct image url in the database entry on firebase realtime database. It just stores an unresolvable url

Comment: Okkk so after uploading image to storage try showing Toast message and see if it shows download url in it and use above statement to get downlaod url.

Comment: I finally figured it out mate. Thanks for the efforts you made. I replaced getDownloadUrl with the resultUri that I declared in the line above it

Comment: Cheers bro Enjoy...  :)